# Command in function not works as manualy typed in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, text, grep

I need to parse document for stuff like this:

```
#00 service.
log: servicelogin
pass: password
```

Don't worry, file is encrypted and separated from system :)
So you see there are 'service' in first line and second, so doing it like this:

```
cat /path | grep -A 3 service
```

Returns 4 lines as it finds service two times.

However, typing in terminal this command:

```
cat /path | grep -A 3 service | grep -A 3 -m 1 "/."
```

Works like a charm.

But! As I need to type 'service' in the end alias isn't good enough. So I created a function:

```
function do-stuff {
    cat /path | grep -A 3 $1 | grep -A 3 -m 1 "/."
}
```

And it works like first one without parsing it again.

That's it. Thank you!

=== edit ===

Sure I've tried to combine it like

```
cat /path | grep -A 3 -m 1 service
```

But it's also won't work. Returns only one line.

=== edit ===

I need to get only 3 lines, not 4 as it finds it again next line.

Comment: Knowing what should be your desired result would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression isn't specific enough. Perhaps something like

```
grep -A 3 '#.* service\.' /path
```

Comment: No, it's not working. In both ways: a) it is needed to search argument to be the last or in function. b) it anyway returns first result (4 lines).

Comment: Why does it need to be last? If you are defining a function, you have control over where the argument goes (which is just one reason *why* you use a function instead of an alias). `do_stuff () { grep -A 3 "$1" /path; }`.

Comment: As I wrote in post: func not working somehow. Function like this [ function do-passlook-mine () { cat $outsidedir/documents/accounts/mine.txt | grep -A 3 "$1" | grep -A 3 -m 1 "\."; } ] without brackets.
BUT!!! This function worked: [ function do-passlook-mine () { grep -A 3 "$1" $outsidedir/documents/accounts/mine.txt | grep -A 3 -m 1 "\."; } ]
Perhaps it didn't like pipes huh. Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you need `-A 3` or two calls to `grep` at all, if you only want the first of the 3 lines? `grep 'service\.' /path`.